# bash script that adds user

Tags: python, bash

I write python script that connected to a Linux server and run a bash script that create user and password.
The password is not set and I don't know why, I thought the random password from python don't send the value to bash script, but if in the bash script I create directory with the password value its create!

python script:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import paramiko
import string
import secrets

def add_user(username, subfolder):
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("x.x.x")
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(8))
    cmd = "add_user %s %s %s" % (username, subfolder, password)

    # Connect/ssh to an instance
    try:
        # Here 'test' is user name and 'instance_ip' is public IP of EC2
        client.connect(hostname="x.x.x.x", username="test", pkey=key)
        # Execute a command(cmd) after connecting/ssh to an instance
        #stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(f"add_user {username} {subfolder} {password}")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
        print (cmd)
        print (password)

        client.close()
    except:
        print ("Something wrong")

add_user('test29', '12asd3')
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

    USERNAME=$1
    SUBFOLDER=$2
    PASSWORD=$3
    sudo useradd -d /home/FTPserver/$USERNAME/ -m $USERNAME
    sudo mkdir -p /home/FTPserver/$USERNAME/$SUBFOLDER
    sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/FTPserver/$USERNAME/$SUBFOLDER
    sudo echo -e "${PASSWORD}\n${PASSWORD}" | passwd $USERNAME
    sudo echo $PASSWORD
```

Comment: Can you try to run your script with sudo?

Comment: like that sudo python your_python_file.py

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 1):

`passwd` is not the right tool for the job, you can use `chpasswd` instead. From `man chpasswd`:

> The chpasswd command reads a list of user name and password pairs from standard input and uses this information to update a group of existing users. Each line is of the format: `user_name:password`

To put it in your script, also make sure to move the `sudo` to execute the right side of the pipe:

```
echo "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" | sudo chpasswd
```

Comment: Can you `print(stderr)` to see if you get an error message?

Comment: Output: add_user test33 12asd3 vG8UyQ6Q

vG8UyQ6Q

<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x298fe6a0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>
link for output: https://ibb.co/Z2n2RBB

Comment: It still does not work, but I must say that if I run the bash script from the Linux its success and when I run the python script with the same bash script its filed.